# installing JVCL (3.45) for XE2 error when loading the group project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jvcl

I installed JCL and I do experience some issues with the `JVCL (release 3.45)` installation. 
If I load the "`D16 Packages.groupproj`" group project file, I get a bunch of popup warnings about missing classes, like e.g.

```
TJvContextProvider
TJvSendMailAction
TJvxCheckListBox
TJvControlCollapseAction
TJvFormStorage
TJvListBox
TJvLabel
TJvBrowserForFolderAction
TJvSpinEdit
TJvFullColorCircle
```

This was already reported in previous threads, but I did not see any comment about how to handle this issue here.

I would be gratefull if someone could provide me with some useful hint here.
thanks in advance for your valuable help here.

Comment: That's years old. Why don't you take the latest from the repo?

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. Sure, I could upgrade but i need to "stick" to that version. Is there some workaround? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can give us a step by step of what you did to get to this point.

Comment: Hi David, here are the steps: download JCL release 2.3.1.4197, In XE2, install JclPackagesD160.groupproj. Then add to the library path source\common, source\includes, source\vcl, source\windows, lib\d16\win32. then simply  download JVCL 3.45 and load the D16 Packages.groupproj.

Comment: Please edit these details into the question

Comment: Why aren't you just using `install.bat` and letting the installer handle all of this for you?

Comment: Your step by step guide is imprecise. Details matter. If you follow the instructions precisely it will work out.

Comment: Hi, apologize for the late reply. I finally moved to the standard install.bat approach, which is way much easier than trying to load the XE2 group packages. thanks for the replies.